# JPA map relation entity parentID

Tags: jpa, dictionary, entity, relation, parentid

could someone help me to understand how can I define an entity with JPA mapping that has a relation with it self?

For example, my entity is CompanyDivision, divisionA contains divisionB, divisionC
and divisionB contains divisionB1, divisionB2

- divisionA

  - divisionB

    - divisionB1
    - divisionB2
  - divisionC

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not different from a relation between 2 different Entities. Here's an example:

```
class CompanyDivision {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentDivision")
    private Set<CompanyDivision> childDivisions = new HashSet<CompanyDivision>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_PARENT_DIVISION")
    private CompanyDivision parentDivision;
}
```

Comment: Do note the remarks in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4397639/1023341 when storing things this way.